# No virtual method getCellSignalStrength()

Tags: android, gsm, indoor-positioning-system, signal-strength

I need the GSM signal strength described in the following paper on android:

[image]

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/308578251_Indoor-Outdoor_Detection_Using_a_Smart_Phone_Sensor

When i run the following code:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO
        return;
    }
    List<CellInfo> cellInfoList = manager.getAllCellInfo();
    System.out.println(cellInfoList.get(0).getCellSignalStrength());
}
```

I get the following error:

```
W/r_detection_ap( 5718): Accessing hidden method Landroid/telephony/CellInfo;->getCellSignalStrength()Landroid/telephony/CellSignalStrength; (blacklist, linking, denied)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718): Process: de.felithium.indoor_outdoor_detection_app, PID: 5718
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getCellSignalStrength()Landroid/telephony/CellSignalStrength; in class Landroid/telephony/CellInfo; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.telephony.CellInfo' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):    at de.felithium.indoor_outdoor_detection_app.MainActivity.lambda$configureFlutterEngine$0$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:43)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):    at de.felithium.indoor_outdoor_detection_app.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$gCCACi3_KGae1eavG8OYIDKJz3Y.onMethodCall(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7710)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5718):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
I/Process ( 5718): Sending signal. PID: 5718 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

I get the error only on my smartphone (One Plus 7 Pro), while it works on the Emulator. According to the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfo) `getCellSignalStrength` was implemented in `SDK Version 17` but both my smartphone and the emulator have `SDK Version 29`. Any ideas why I get this error or if there is another way to get the desired values consistently?

Comment: Same problem here. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: This worked for me: https://pastebin.com/NznXk882